# how to find csv files that do not contain NA values

Tags: r

I have over 1000 csv files. Some of them have NA values and some don't have. So, I want to know which csv files dun hve NA values. I would like to get a name list of csv files that do not have NA.

Comment: A strategy could be to loop through your csvs (if they have similar names), read them in each iteration and check if they are `NA` free (something like `length(is.na(df))==0`).

Comment: I agree with @boski, you should read each csv (see `readr::read_csv` for faster performance) in a directory (you can `list.files` in a path) and check whether there is any `NA` using `sum(is.na(df))==0` and save that to a vector that contains the file names. Without a minimal, reproducible example I can't give you exact code, but you should be able to figure out what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your csv files/ input and use something like :

```
absent_NA <- vector() # vector containing names of CSV without any NA

if (sum(is.na(X))==0) {

  absent_NA <- append(absent_NA, deparse(substitute(X)))

}
```

X is your csv object